# -$\log (1-|z|^2)$ subharmonic in the unit disk?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

By unit disk, I mean $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.

I suppose the answer is yes if one shows that $\frac{1}{1-|z|^2}$ is subharmonic (since if $u$ is subharmonic and nonnegative, then $\log u$ is subharmonic too).  Is $\frac{1}{1-|z|^2}$  subharmonic?

But maybe $-\log (1-|z|^2)$ isn't subharmonic on the unit disk? I would be grateful for any comments/help. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I now know that for a $C^2$ function, subharmonicity of $u$ follows by showing $\Delta u\geq 0$, so this can be checked directly. Apologies.

Comment: Check the laplacian using polar coordinates as the function is only in $r$ so it is easy to compute it